# Faced: error: unknown option `app' when try to deploy Laravel project to Heroku

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all, I want to deploy my Laravel project to Heroku and when I used "git push heroku master --app testtask" there occured an error: error: unknown option `app'. Please can anyone tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: `git push` does not have a parameter called `app`.

Comment: @feeela, should I use git push heroku master instead of git push heroku master --app testtask?

Comment: I don't know about heroku, but have you tried that?

Comment: @feeela, I faced this error: error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/testtask.git'

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
git push heroku master
```